# How can I convert CSV to JSON using node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, csv, data-conversion

I try to convert CSV from Clash Royale.

I wanna push number in rows to array

real csv data header or property is over 40 properties

example data:

| name | level count | upgrade cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| common | 14 | 5 |
|  |  | 20 |
|  |  | 50 |
|  |  | 100 |
| rare | 12 | 50 |
|  |  | 150 |
|  |  | 400 |
|  |  | 1000 |

my node.js code:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const papa = require("papaparse")

const results = []
const options = { header: true, dynamicTyping: true }

fs.createReadStream("rarities.csv")
    .pipe(papa.parse(papa.NODE_STREAM_INPUT, options))
    .on("data", (data) => results.push(data))
    .on("end", () => console.log(results))
```

output expecting:

```
     [
           {
               name: "common",
               level_count: 14,
               upgrade_cost: [5, 20, 50, 100]
           },
           {
               name: "rare",
               level_count: 12,
               upgrade_cost: [50, 150, 400, 1000]
           },
       ]
```

Comment: Use .reduce to combine results further

Comment: Also tbh, this isn’t valid/proper csv

Answer (score 2):

You should try somethings like that I guess

```js
.on("end", () => {
  let savedName, savedLevelCount

  const goupedByNameAndLevelCount = results.reduce((acc, { name, level_count, upgrade_cost }) => {
    if (name && level_count) {
      savedName = name
      savedLevelCount = level_count
    }
    acc[savedName] ||= {}
    acc[savedName][savedLevelCount] ||= []
    acc[savedName][savedLevelCount].push(upgrade_cost)
    return acc
  }, {})
  const preciousData = Object.entries(goupedByNameAndLevelCount).map(([name, groupedByLevelCount]) => {
    return Object.entries(groupedByLevelCount).map(([level_count, upgrade_cost]) => ({
      name,
      level_count,
      upgrade_cost
    }))
  })
  console.log(preciousData)
})
```

**Sample**

With this as results

```js
const results = [
  { name: 'common', level_count: 14, upgrade_cost: 5 },
  { upgrade_cost: 20 },
  { upgrade_cost: 50 },
  { upgrade_cost: 100 },
  { name: 'rare', level_count: 12, upgrade_cost: 50 },
  { upgrade_cost: 150 },
  { upgrade_cost: 400 },
  { upgrade_cost: 1000 },
]
```

we get

```js
[
  [
    {
      "name": "common",
      "level_count": "14",
      "upgrade_cost": [
        5,
        20,
        50,
        100
      ]
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "name": "rare",
      "level_count": "12",
      "upgrade_cost": [
        50,
        150,
        400,
        1000
      ]
    }
  ]
]
```

Comment: the problem is my data props is over 40. do you have any idea to make it dynamic?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `convert-csv-to-json` npm package

```
npm i convert-csv-to-json
```

your csv file is `rarities.csv` and you have to create one more file `rarities_output.csv` for this

```
csvToJson.generateJsonFileFromCsv(rarities.csv,rarities_output.csv);
```

and for further you should read this official documentation [convert-csv-to-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/convert-csv-to-json)

Comment: output was not what I expected

Comment: for more you can visit on their official documentation https://www.npmjs.com/package/convert-csv-to-json